# PUT operation with Spring Rest Data and Rest Template

Tags: spring, rest, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

I have a question how to make a PUT operation with Spring REST DATA and RestTemplate to update a relation between two beans.

I am successfully updating with curl, but I could not manage to do it with RestTemplate.

```
curl -i -X PUT -d 'http://localhost:8383/services/67' -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" localhost:8383/routes/135/service
```

This works, it updates my Route object with a reference to Service object 67 but I try to do this with following RestTemplate, it is not.

```
 ResponseEntity<Route> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8383/routes/", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Route.class);
    if(responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED) {

        HttpHeaders reqHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        reqHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, new MediaType("text", "uri-list").toString());
        HttpEntity<Service> requestEntityService = new HttpEntity<>(service, reqHeaders);
        restTemplate.put("http://localhost:8383/routes/" + responseEntity.getBody().getId() + "/service", requestEntityService);
    }
```

If I try to this, it complains about it can't find any MessageConverter's for 'uri-list' but if I remove the 'uri-list' then Spring Rest Data responds with '404' because it seems it does this operation only with 'uri-list'..

While I also use the Spring HATEOAS project, I defined a special MessageConvter,....

```
@Bean
private RestTemplate prepareRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setDefaultCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/hal+json"));     converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    return restTemplateBuilder.messageConverters(converter).build();
}
```

This works perfectly for POST operation and creating beans in Spring Rest Data, do I also have to defined MediaType 'uri-list' here.

I see lot of examples in the  internet how to do this with curl but none how to do it with RestTemplate, of course I can use HttpClient to do this but naturally this will be weird.

Any tips?

Thx for answers